# Entity framework get customers by zip code

Tags: entity-framework

So I have by entity framework 5 set up. I have a Customers table in the database.  What would be most efficient way to get customers of a given zip code for example 94023?  I have this:

```
var customersOfLosAltos = 
    (myDbContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>()).Where(c=>c.Zip == "94023");
```

But, intuitively, that seems pretty inefficient because as I understand it, it basically retrieves all customers from the data source, and then filter it out by the given zip.  It might be OK if I only have a few hundred customers, what if I have a million customers?

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: So, that only creates a query and will not execute immediately?

Comment: Speed will depend on whether & how the zipcode column is indexed in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> as I understand it, it basically retrieves all customers from the data source, and then filter it out by the given zip.

Your understanding is wrong. Entity framework turns your code in to a SQL query, so what the server actually returns is the result for the query

```
select * from Customer where Zip = '94023'
```

If you changed your code to

```
var customers = myDbContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>().ToList();
var customersOfLosAltos= customers.Where(c=>c.Zip == "94023");
```

then because of that `.ToList()` it now does a unfiltered query to the database then in memory filters on the client it to just the customers you want. This is why you want to try to keep your query as a `IQueryable` for as long as possible before you get the results because any tweaks or changes you make to the query propagate back to the query performed on the server.

To make your query even more efficient you could add a `Select` clause

```
var lastNamesOfCustomersOfLosAltos = (myDbContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>())
                                      .Where(c=>c.Zip == "94023")
                                      .Select(c=>c.LastName);
```

The SQL server now performs the query (when you retreive the results via a `ToList()`, or in a `foreach`, or via a `.AsEnumerable()`, ect.)

```
select LastName from Customer where Zip = '94023'
```

Comment: OK, got it. That answers my question. Thanks.